# ArgumentNullException in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi I wanted to move data from one listbox to another,But When I move the data I get Error…
I have done the following code for that in **View**

```
<td>
<%:Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.objMemberAccessRights.Id) %>
<%:Html.ListBoxFor(model =>model.objMemberAccessRights.AvailableSelected, newMultiSelectList(Model.objMemberAccessRights.AvailableNames, "Id", "InstituteName", Model.objMemberAccessRights.AvailableSelected), new { size="8"})%>
</td>

<td>
<br/>

<buttontype="button"id="add"onclick="location.href='<%:Url.Action("AddNames", "MemberDetails") %>'">>></button>
<br/>

<br/>
<buttontype="button"id="remove"onclick="location.href='<%:Url.Action("RemoveNames", "MemberDetails") %>'"><<</button>

</td>

<td>
<%:Html.ListBoxFor(model=>model.objMemberAccessRights.RequestedSelected,newMultiSelectList(Model.objMemberAccessRights.RequestedNames,"Id","InstituteName",Model.objMemberAccessRights.RequestedSelected), new { size="8"}) %>
</td>
```

**Model:**

```
    public class MemberAccessRights
    {
public int Id { get; set; }

public List<InstituteInformation> AvailableNames { get; set; }
public string[] AvailableSelected { get; set; }

public List<InstituteInformation> RequestedNames { get; set; }
public string[] RequestedSelected { get; set; }

public string SavedRequested { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
        [NonAction]
public List<InstituteInformation> getAllInstituteNameList()
        {
var name = (from i indb.InstituteInformationDBSselect i).ToList();
return name;
        }

//
// GET: /MemberDetails/Create
public ActionResult Create()
        {
MemberDetailsWrapper MD = new MemberDetailsWrapper();
MD.objMemberAccessRights = new MemberAccessRights{ AvailableNames = getAllInstituteNameList(), RequestedNames = new List<InstituteInformation>() };

return View(MD);
        }


//AddNames
public ActionResult AddNames(MemberDetailsWrapper MD, string add)
        {
ModelState.Clear();
MemberAccessRights MAR=new MemberAccessRights();
RestoreSavedState(MAR);

if (!add.Equals(">>"))
            {
if (MD.objMemberAccessRights.AvailableSelected != null)
                {
var names = getAllInstituteNameList().Where(p => MD.objMemberAccessRights.AvailableSelected.Contains(p.InstituteName));
MD.objMemberAccessRights.RequestedNames.AddRange(names);
                    MD.objMemberAccessRights.AvailableSelected = null;
                }
            }
SaveState(MD);
return View(MD);
        }


//RemoveNames
public ActionResult RemoveNames(MemberDetailsWrapper MD, string remove)
        {
ModelState.Clear();

RestoreSavedState(MD);
if (!remove.Equals("<<"))
            {
if (MD.objMemberAccessRights.RequestedSelected != null)
                {
MD.objMemberAccessRights.RequestedNames.RemoveAll(p => MD.objMemberAccessRights.RequestedSelected.Contains(p.InstituteName));
MD.objMemberAccessRights.RequestedSelected = null;
                }
            }
SaveState(MD);
return View(MD);
        }

        #regionSupportFuncs

public void SaveState(MemberDetailsWrapper MD)
        {
MD.objMemberAccessRights.SavedRequested = string.Join(",", MD.objMemberAccessRights.RequestedNames.Select(p =>p.InstituteName).ToArray());

////Available Names = All - Requested
MD.objMemberAccessRights.AvailableNames = getAllInstituteNameList().Except(MD.objMemberAccessRights.RequestedNames).ToList();

        }

    //RestoreSavedState
public void RestoreSavedState(MemberAccessRights MAR)
        {
MAR.RequestedNames = new List<InstituteInformation>();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MAR.SavedRequested))
            { 
string[] nameids = MAR.SavedRequested.Split(',');
var name = getAllInstituteNameList().Where(p =>nameids.Contains(p.InstituteName));
MAR.RequestedNames.AddRange(name);
            }
        }   

        #endregion
```

When I click on this >>button then I get Error:
ArgumentNullException

**This is happen because:**
When I check this(RestoreSavedState(MAR);) after debugging it shows

```
AvailableNames null
AvailableSelected null
RequestedNames null
RequestedSelected null
```

That’s why its not running properly and shows the Exception 
it should be display like this

```
AvailableNames null
AvailableSelected<Array of selected item> like this,{int[1]}
RequestedNames null
RequestedSelected null
```

All this Happens Because the object is not passing correctly can anyone tell me how to remove this bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line of code:

```
if (MD == null || MD.objMemberAccessRights == null)
{
//do nothing
}else{
MD.objMemberAccessRights.RequestedNames = newList<InstituteInformation>(); 
}
```

You probably have the nullreference exception since one of these objects is not intialised.
For your application to function correctly you should try to find out why these values are null

Comment: After doing this it shows Error **Operator '|| can not be applied to the operand of type bool and SHGMngmnt.Models.MemberAccessRights'**

Comment: @user3595779  modified my answer, forgot some :), you should verify if the object is not null, and then with the && (and also) operator check for the other one to. If both not null you can proceed

Comment: @user3595779  If you break, can you inspect the elements and check which one is actually null? Could it be you perform some action in the setter of 'RequestedNames' that tries to access a null object? Or perhaps you have the nullref exception on some other part now?

Comment: When i debug the code it shows MD.objMemberAccessRights as null

Comment: After Doing the Above code as u sugesset the exception is goibg to the next line **if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MD.objMemberAccessRights.SavedRequested))**

Comment: then place all that cod ein the validation block. It seems more the problem that your object is not correctly build. Hence the nullref exception...

Comment: @ Jeroen, i have update the question please check it and tell me how to solve this